# How to convert Amazon QLDB IonStruct to Json in java?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-qldb, amazon-ion

I have written a QLDB query to fetch a document by document ID So that I want to convert this document to a JSON response and pass it through the rest end point.

```
qldbDriver.QldbDriver().execute(txn ->{

            IonSystem ionSys = IonSystemBuilder.standard().build();
            Result result = txn.execute("SELECT * FROM _ql_committed_WALLET  WHERE metadata.id = ?",ionSys.newString(id));
            IonStruct person = (IonStruct) result.iterator().next();
            String s = person.get("data").toPrettyString();
           
        });
```

Here I want that conversation.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you are trying to do. But picking up from your example, you might want to convert your result `person` into JSON directly, or you might want to use a library to generate that JSON. If it possible to convert from `IonValue` (of which `IonStruct` is an instance) to POJOs and then you could convert those to JSON using Jackson.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.ion.IonObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

...

IonValue personValue = qldbDriver.QldbDriver().execute(txn ->{
  IonSystem ionSys = IonSystemBuilder.standard().build();
  Result result = txn.execute("SELECT * FROM _ql_committed_WALLET  WHERE metadata.id = ?",ionSys.newString(id));
  return (IonStruct) result.iterator().next();
  
});
Person person = IonObjectMapper.builder().build().readValue(personValue, Person.class);
String personJson = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(person);
```

In this example we are taking the `IonValue` as returned from QLDB and converting it to a POJO using the [Jackson Ion library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary/tree/master/ion). Then we use the [regular JSON Jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) to convert that same `Person` POJO into a JSON string which you can then send over your REST connection as the body of the response.

Comment: Again Thanks @alpian