# How to convert amazon ion to json data using java

Tags: javascript, java, json, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-ion

I'm working with amazon ion data, stored in file. I need to convert it to Json data. Is there any libraries available in Java?
Or any another type of data format close to Json?

**Task I'm doing**

I have fetched the data from dynamoDB, which generated the `.txt` file having this type of data, which is ion format (separated by new line).

```
{group:{s:"accounts"},rId:{s:"Ada_Invoice"},item:{s:"System Issue"},environments:{ss:["Env:Ada/Alpha"]},category:{s:"Publish"},type:{s:"Ada"},groups:{ss:["ada-admins"]}}
```

I have to consolidate this data around `environment`.
I want to convert the ion to JSONObject, so that i can perform `.get()` around keys.

P.S. - newbie to java

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to get the DynamoDB Json (i.e. with the "ss" and "s" keys intact) or are you trying to get "normal" Json?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use Jackson Ion library to convert ion data to POJO, then conver the POJO to JSON.

Check more details in the answer here - [How to convert Amazon QLDB IonStruct to Json in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68039063/how-to-convert-amazon-qldb-ionstruct-to-json-in-java)